# Custom HTTP Header, does it violate the RESTful Architecture

Tags: rest, api

I'm currently working on designing a RESTful API, my question is, does it violate the RESTful Architecture if adding custom HTTP Header as part of the requirements?

`X-API-Token: MyToken`

Appreciate the help, thank you!

Erson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you do not store client context as part your custom header, you're good to go.